# Entity framework throws NullReferenceException

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Entity framework's ToListAsync throws a NullReferenceException when reading from a database view.

We are using entity framework database first. One of our queries is now throwing a  NullReferenceException. I have tried running the SQL generated by the framework in SQL Server Managemen Studio. It gives the expected result.

Minimal code to provoke the error:

```
IQueryable<ReportForICC> query = Context.ReportForICC;
List<ReportForICC> result = await query.ToListAsync();
```

Our query of course has a where clause, but even when this is removed, we get the error.

`query` is not null.

Part of the definition of the class of the context object:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

…

 internal partial class ClearViewTradeEntities : DbContext
    {
        public ClearViewTradeEntities()
            : base("name=ClearViewTradeEntities")
        {
        }

…

         public virtual DbSet<ReportForICC> ReportForICC { get; set; }

…

     }
```

The entity class:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace ClearViewTrade
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class ReportForICC
    {
        public string AccreditationNumber { get; set; }
        public string Certificatenumber { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime ApprovedDate { get; set; }
        public string ExporterName { get; set; }
        public string SecurityNumber { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Endorserid { get; set; }
        public int AttachmentCount { get; set; }
        public int EndorserId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

We have added some properties:

```
public partial class ReportForICC : IClearTradeObject, IReport
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public int? Version { get; set; }
    public int ConsignorId { get; set; }
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    public int RequestingOrganisationId { get; set; }
}
```

Some are columns we have on every table, but which do not make sense in a view. We add them to match our interface for data objects. This works for every other view. The others are columns we have on every other report. Again, they are needed to match an interface.

The error we get is

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Objektreferencen er ikke indstillet til en forekomst af et objekt.'

Stack trace:

```
   ved System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityKey.ValidateTypeOfKeyValue(MetadataWorkspace workspace, EdmMember keyMember, Object keyValue, Boolean isArgumentException, String argumentName)
   ved System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityKey.ValidateEntityKey(MetadataWorkspace workspace, EntitySet entitySet, Boolean isArgumentException, String argumentName)
   ved System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateManager.CheckKeyMatchesEntity(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySetForType, Boolean forAttach)
   ved System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateManager.AddEntry(IEntityWrapper wrappedObject, EntityKey passedKey, EntitySet entitySet, String argumentName, Boolean isAdded)
   ved System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly[TEntity](Func`2 constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet)
   ved lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
   ved System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper)
   ved System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.<MoveNextAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- Afslutningen på staksporingen fra den tidligere placering, hvor undtagelsen blev udløst ---
   ved System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   ved System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   ved System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyAsyncEnumerator`1.<FirstMoveNextAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- Afslutningen på staksporingen fra den tidligere placering, hvor undtagelsen blev udløst ---
   ved System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   ved System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   ved System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbAsyncEnumerableExtensions.<ForEachAsync>d__5`1.MoveNext()
--- Afslutningen på staksporingen fra den tidligere placering, hvor undtagelsen blev udløst ---
   ved System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   ved System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   ved System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   ved ClearViewTrade.WorkBench.BackgroundServiceTest.<TestReportWiew>d__6.MoveNext() i C:\newclone\ClearViewTrade\ClearViewTrade\ClearViewTrade.Tests\BackgroundServiceTest.cs:linje 513
```

Comment: is ReportForICC virtual, does it have a public getter and setter?

Comment: Show us the `ReportForICC` class, and your context. There's not enough in here for us to help I'm afraid.

Comment: I have added the relevant part of the autogenerated context object.

Comment: I have added the entity class.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the view so that it returns '' rather than null for SecurityNumber fixed the problem. Why I have no idea.